# Counter act javascript .click or alternative to a href

Tags: php, javascript

I currently have a site and a javascript running in the header

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('a').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 document.location.href='shows.php?ref='+this.href;
 return false;
 });
 });
 </script>
```

It changes all < a href > tags. Now I added a php include to include a nav bar. The problem is the javascript also changes the nav links which makes them fail.

Is there a alternative to the a in a href or can I counteract the javascript in the nav page or can I exclude the nav page in my current javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Use a proper selector to narrow down the selection. Assuming the real content is in a `div` with ID `content`, use

```
$('#content a').click(function(){...});
```

You didn't post your HTML structure, but this should give you the right idea. Add the ID if necessary.

Comment: This is brilliant! Gives me a lot more control and solves a couple other issues to! Can I include multiple contents? 

$('#content, #content1, #content2 a').click(function(){...});

Will that work?
Thanks :)

Comment: @Michael: You can have *several* IDs, but every ID has to be unique. If you want to address multiple elements with the same name, use classes.

Comment: @Michael: And an element can only have **one** ID.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you can select you navigation with a selector, eg

```
<div id="nav"><!-- your links --></div>
```

You can select all link except those in the navigation with

```
$("a:not(#nav)").click(/* your function */);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it seems that I was indeed wrong.
This reads as:
Select al <a/> elements, except <a id="nav"/> elements.

Answer (score 0):

you could unbind the  click event handler for the anchor elements in the nav bar.
Say that your nav bar container is identified by an id="nav_bar_id". Then, you could do something like :

```
$('#nav_bar_id a').unbind('click');
```

this will remove the onclick handler from the desired `<a>`'s without modifying the previous script

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude your nav links of that behaviour (instead of attaching the behaviour to some links), give them a class, and then, in your javascript:

`$('a').not('.nav_class').click(function(e){...});`